# Virtualenv not finding imported modules

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a project that I packaged with virtualenv. It installed setuptools & pip fine and set up all the necessary folders. I than ran `source bin/activate` and installed the necessary libraries for my project: xmlutils, configparser.

I compressed the project folder into a zip and then tried to use it on another computer. I was able to run `source bin/activate` without problems. However, once I ran my script, the module xmlutils was not found. I dug into the "libs/site-packages" folder of the project and it is clearly there.

Is it because I have to install virtualenv on the other computer?

Here is the organization of my project with virtualenv set up:

project: 
        bin
        include
        lib
        lib64
        projectScript.py
        projectScript2.py

Comment: Why not just `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then re-create the venv on a different computer with `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: the problem lies in PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When constructing a virtualenv it is tied to a specific path meaning that you cannot rename it or move it. If you wish to create a movable virtualenv then you can use the `--relocatable` option as given in the docs [here](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#making-environments-relocatable).

The command needed for making a virtualenv relocatable is:

```
virtualenv --relocatable ENV
```

Note two things:

1. This is experimental and not guaranteed to work.
2. The above command must be ran again if you add any new packages to the virtualenv.

Additionally (as I mentioned in a comment) you can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to save a text file containing all the package requirements from the pip inside your virtualenv. You can then install these packages in a new virtualenv using the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Thanks. Is this normally how dependencies are handled? I'm new to Python and don't really know much. I've searched a bit and there is another tool called distutils.

Comment: `distutils` is used for building and installing packages, for example I could build my own code base and then bundle it into a package using distutils or setuptools. When you're looking to install packages the main method of installing them is using pip (assuming they are in the pypi collection of packages). If they're not in pypi then typically you download some code and it will include a setup.py file and you install it with `python setup.py install`. This is the more complicated way of doing it, I would recommend you using pip if you can :)

Comment: And also: using a virtualenv is definitely a good idea, it helps to keep all of your libraries separated, especially if you want to work with different versions of the same library (for example library 1.0 on one project and library 1.1 on another).